# Curl: use login form

Tags: curl

I need curl to login to a webpage and save the cookie id for later use.

I've tried various things such as

```
curl -k -c cookies.txt --data "txtUser=admin&txtPassword=password&cmdLogin=Login"https://192.168.1.1/login.html
```

but I can't get it working. Looks like the data isn't submitted.

The code of the page looks like this

```
<form id="loginForm">
   <table style="margin:auto;width:1%">
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td class="labelCell">User</td>
         <td><input tabindex="1" id="txtUser" name="txtUser" type="text" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="labelCell">Password</td>
         <td><input tabindex="2" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" type="password" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;padding-top:30px">
            <input tabindex="3" name="cmdLogin" value="Login" type="submit" />
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Javascript request from the webpage

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
var msgDiv;getStNavList();$(function(){msgDiv=$("#msgDiv");$("form").bind("submit",function(a){a.preventDefault();$.ajax({type:"POST",url:cgiScriptUrl,data:{user:$("#txtUser").val(),password:$("#txtPassword").val()},dataType:"text",async:false,success:function(b){if(b=="loggedin"){msgDiv.removeClass().addClass(successDivClass).html("Login successful").slideDown("slow");setTimeout("redirect()",1500)}else{msgDiv.removeClass().addClass(errorDivClass).html("Login failed").slideDown("slow");setTimeout("msgDiv.slideUp('slow')",2000)}}})});$("#txtUser").focus()});function redirect(){fullUrl=parent.document.URL;var a=fullUrl.indexOf("?")+1;if(a>0){window.location=fullUrl.substring(a,fullUrl.length)}else{window.location="general_status.html"}}function pollerror(a){if(a==undefined){a="Polling error"}$("#msgDiv").removeClass().addClass(errorDivClass).html(a).show()};</script>
```

Comment: That form has neither an action nor a method set - and since I doubt that anyone would send login credentials using the default method GET these days, I’d suspect that there might be some JS that reads this data and sends it to the server - maybe in a different format then just sending this form the normal way would …? Start by checking out what actual request this cases using your browser dev tools.

Comment: edited first post

Comment: edited first post

Comment: No, please don’t post extended code in comments, that is unreadable. Edit your question instead to include the additional information.

Comment: edited first post